# how to add login form validation errors inside the login form

Tags: php

Hi please excuse the rookie question as I am still very much learning PHP. Im trying to do a basic form validation. Im trying to get any errors found upon validation to be displayed in red inside the form field.

how to add login form validation errors inside the login form the error msg is not coming inside the loginform

```html
<form  action="test.php" method="POST" >
                    <div class="logintable ">
                        <table  class="applyfont" style="border: 1px solid lightseagreen">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="login1">
                                    <td class="applyfontbold"><b>Login </b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" id="uname">
                                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $passeErr;?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"> </p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="login-help applyfontlighter">
                                            <p>Forgot your password? <span id="footer"><u style="color:red;"><a href="#">Click here to reset it.</a></u></span></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <p id="new"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >New Registers</button></p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

```html
<?php

$nameErr = "";
$passErr = "";
$x = "typepass";
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $nameErr .= "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $passeErr .= "password is required";
    } elseif ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {
        $passeErr .= "password doesn't match";
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    echo "Username :" . " " . $name . "<br>" . "Password :" . " " . $password;
}
?>
```

Comment: in which html tag do you want the error to be displayed?

Comment: after the input field username and password both field under display the errors

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you are setting 2 vars when there are errors:

```
$passeErr
$nameErr
```

You could add a new html tag inside your login form like

```
<span class="error"></span>
```

And inside this span you can use php to see if the vars are set. If they are you display them. if they are not you do nothing like so:

You use `isset` for this. In your example you try to echo the errors all the time. Even when they are not set before logging in. This will produce warnings.

error for password

```
<span class="error">
   if(isset($passeErr)){
     echo $passeErr;
   }
</span>
```

error for name

```
<span class="error">
   if(isset($nameErr)){
      echo $nameErr;
   }
</span>
```

Now make sure you do your form validation above the form and it should work!

Comment: Replace your current <span class="error"> with the one above. This way it is not trying to echo a var that is not set before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$x = "typepass";
if (isset(trim($_POST['save']))) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
        $passeErr = "password is required";
    } elseif ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {
        $passeErr = "password doesn't match";
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
if(isset($nameErr)||(isset($passErr)))
{
 echo $nameErr . "<br>" .$passErr;
}
else // no error
{
 echo "Username :" . " " . $name . "<br>" . "Password :" . " " . $password;
}

}
?>
```